# Variable from GUI to remote computer

Tags: wpf, powershell, user-interface

I build a gui with WPF and manage the actions with powershell. I have multiple textboxes and need to pass the text in the Textboxes to New-ADUser command via invoke-command

I've tried to use the $Using: variable to pass the text

My GUI:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
       Title="Active Directory Tool" Height="500" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <!-- Definiere das Hauptlayout als Raster (Grid) -->
    <Grid x:Name="grid">

        <!-- Navigationsmen� (linke Spalte) -->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Stilisiertes Men� mit Hintergrundverlauf und Schaltfl�chen -->
        <Border x:Name="MenuBorder" Grid.Column="0" Width="220" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Border.Background>
                <!-- Hintergrundverlauf f�r das Men� -->
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFD8C0" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#C0D8FF" Offset="1.0"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>

            <!-- Schaltfl�chenanordnung im Men� -->
            <UniformGrid x:Name="MenuGrid" Rows="2" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <!-- Button f�r "User umbenennen" -->
                <Button x:Name="RenameButton"
                    Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" IsTabStop="False">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="StackRename" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image x:Name="RenameImage" Source="D:\Test\WpfApp1\WpfApp1\rename.png" Width="40" Height="40"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="RenameTextBlock" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"><Run Text="User umbenennen"/></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>

                <!-- Button f�r "User Referenz" -->
                <Button x:Name="ReferenceButton"
                    Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" IsTabStop="False">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelReferenceButton" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image x:Name="ReferenceImage" Source="D:\Test\WpfApp1\WpfApp1\users.png" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ReferenceTextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,38.9,0" FontSize="20"><Run Text="User Referenz"/></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </UniformGrid>
        </Border>

        <!-- Hauptinhalt (rechte Spalte) -->
        <Border x:Name="MainContentBorder" Grid.Column="1">

            <!-- Stapelpanel f�r den Inhalt der rechten Spalte -Ansicht -->
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- Stackpanel f�r den Inhalt vom User Referenz Men� -->
                <StackPanel x:Name="stackpanelReferenz" Margin="20" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelInfo" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image x:Name="InfoImage" Source="D:\Test\WpfApp1\WpfApp1\info.png" Width="30" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="InfoTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="510" Margin="10,0,0,0" >
                Mit dieser Funktion wird ein Benutzer im Active Directory erstellt, dabei werden die selben Rechte des Referenz Users verwendet.
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>


                    <Label x:Name="ReferenceUserLabel" Content="Referenz Benutzer (Anmeldename):" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <Border x:Name="borderReferenceTxtBox" BorderBrush="DodgerBlue" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" Margin="0,0,275,0">
                        <TextBox x:Name="ReferenceUserTextBox" MaxWidth="300" Padding="2" />
                    </Border>

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,10,10,0">
                            <Label x:Name="NewUserUsernameLabel" Content="Anmeldename neuer Benutzer:" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="NewUserUsernameTextBox"/>

                            <Label x:Name="FirstNameLabel" Content="Vorname:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="FirstNameTextBox"/>

                            <Label x:Name="RaumLabel" Content="Raum:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="RaumTextBox"/>

                            <Label x:Name="FaxLabel" Content="Fax:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="FaxTextbox" />
                            
                            
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                            <Label x:Name="LastNameLabel" Content="Nachname:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="LastNameTextBox"/>

                            <Label x:Name="PositionLabel" Content="Position:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="PositionBox"  />

                            <Label x:Name="NummerLabel" Content="Telefonnummer:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="NummerTextBox" />
                            
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                    <Button x:Name="btnCreateUser1" Content="Benutzer erstellen" Margin="40,90,50,0" Width="305" Height="36"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <!-- StackPanel f�r Umbenennen -->
                <StackPanel  x:Name="stackpanelUmbenennen" Margin="20" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelInfo2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                        <Image x:Name="InfoImage2" Source="D:\Test\WpfApp1\WpfApp1\info.png" Width="30" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="InfoTextBlock2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="490" Margin="10,0,0,0">
        Mit dieser Funktion wird ein neuer Benutzer im Active Directory erstellt, es werden die selben Rechte benutzt, jedoch wird der Name umbenannt. Dabei k�nnen einzelne Benutzer umge�ndert werden oder es kann eine Datei hochgeladen werden.
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <!-- StackPanel for RadioButtons -->
                    <Border BorderBrush="#C0D8FF" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                        <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelRadioButtons" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label x:Name="RadioLabel" Content="Auswahl der Option:" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButtonOption1" Content="Einzelne Benutzer" Margin="30,5,0,0" />
                            <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButtonOption2" Content="Mehrere Benutzer" Margin="50,5,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <!-- StackPanel f�r Steuerelemente im Men� einzelne User umbenennen -->
                    <StackPanel x:Name="StackPaneleinzelnerUser" Margin="0,50,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <Label x:Name="alterBenutzername" Content="Alter Benutzername:" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="OldUsernameTextBox" MaxWidth="300" Margin="0,0,275,0" />
                        <Label x:Name="neuerBenutzername" Content="Neuer Benutzername:" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="NewUsernameTextBox" MaxWidth="300" Margin="0,0,275,0" />
                        <Button x:Name="btnCreateUser2" Content="Ausf�hren" Margin="40,133,50,0" Width="305" Height="36"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <!-- StackPanel f�r Steuerelemente im Men� mehrere User umbenennen -->
                    <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelMehrereUser" Margin="0,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelInfo3" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                            <Image x:Name="InfoImage3" Source="D:\Test\WpfApp1\WpfApp1\info.png" Width="40" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,30,0,0"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="InfoTextBlock3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="510" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                            Es kann nur eine CSV Datei hochgeladen werden. Achten Sie dabei auf die folgenden Formatierungen: <LineBreak/><LineBreak/>
                            <BulletDecorator>
                                <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                                        <Ellipse Height="5" Width="5" Fill="Black" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                                </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                                <TextBlock Text="Das Trennzeichen muss ein Semikolon sein" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                            </BulletDecorator>
                                <LineBreak></LineBreak>
                            <BulletDecorator>
                                <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                                        <Ellipse Height="5" Width="5" Fill="Black" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                                </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                                <TextBlock Text="Die erste Spalte muss die �berschrift 'alterName' tragen" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                            </BulletDecorator>
                            <LineBreak></LineBreak>
                            <BulletDecorator>
                                <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                                        <Ellipse Height="5" Width="5" Fill="Black" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                                </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                                <TextBlock Text="Die erste Spalte muss die �berschrift 'neuerName' tragen" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                            </BulletDecorator>
                        </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Content="Hochzuladende Datei:" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,30,0,0" />
                            <TextBox x:Name="UploadFileTextBox" MaxWidth="500" Margin="0,30,0,0" Grid.Column="1" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Button x:Name="btnUploadFile" Content="Durchsuchen" Margin="100,10,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="150"/>
                        <Button x:Name="btnCreateUser3" Content="Ausf�hren" Margin="40,70,50,0" Width="305" Height="36"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My Code is like this:

```
 $btnCreateUser1.Add_click({
    if (-not ($ReferenceUserTextBox.Text -eq "" -or $NewUserUsernameTextBox.Text -eq "" -or $FirstNameTextBox.Text -eq "" -or $RaumTextBox.Text -eq "" -or $FaxTextbox.Text -eq "" -or $LastNameTextBox.Text -eq "" -or $PositionBox.Text -eq "" -or $NummerTextBox.Text -eq "")){
        try {
            $oldinformation = Invoke-Command -ComputerName dc -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {Get-Aduser -identity $using:ReferenceUserTextBox.Text -Properties * -Credential $Using:cred}
            $Passwort = 'fdsojfoji'
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName dc -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
                New-ADUser -Credential $Using:cred `
                -SamAccountName "tesetuser123" `
                -UserPrincipalName "$($Using:NewUserUsernameTextBox.Text)@test.de" `
                -Name "$Using:FirstNameTextBox.Text $Using.LastNameTextBox.Text"`
                -GivenName $Using:FirstNameTextBox.Text `
                -Surname $Using:LastNameTextBox.Text `
                -Enabled $true `
                -DisplayName "$($Using:LastNameTextBox.Text), $($Using:FirstNameTextBox.Text)" `
                -Path ($Using:oldinformation.DistinguishedName).Split(",",2)[1] `
                -City "..." `
                -PostalCode "..." `
                -Country "..." `
                -State "..." `
                -Company $Using:oldinformation.company `
                -StreetAddress $Using:oldinformation.StreetAddress `
                -OfficePhone $Using:NummerTextBox.text `
                -Department $Using:oldinformation.Department `
                -Office $Using:RaumTextBox.Text `
                -Title $Using:PositionBox.Text `
                -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Passwort -AsPlainText -Force) `
                -HomeDirectory "\\...\user\Home\$($Using:NewUserUsernameTextBox.Text)" `
                -Homedrive "U" 
              }
```

I guess the problem is that the variable cant be dissolved because the .Text

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking, but pretty sure the value passed to Name will ignore the $Using since it is part of a string constant. Try changing it to -Name $Using:FirstNameTextBox.Text $Using:LastNameTextBox.Text without the quotes.

Comment: Let me summaraize my problem a bit more. I want to pass the input text in GUI to a remote computer. Like if i write in a textbox a value like name i want to create a new AD User with this name. The Variables for the gui elements are definied local and i thought i can pass them with $using: 

Even the other parameters without quotes cannot dissolve the variable

Comment: Perhaps if you show the result of the command above. I'm fairly certain that the usage of ".Text" is not a problem, but without seeing the output, it's very difficult to form any opinions on exactly what is happening.

Comment: I edited my first post also with the code for gui. It creates the account but without the information which is given in Givenname, name like everywhere i have .Text

Comment: I tested not something else. I created a new variable with the input in the textbox like
$user = $FirstNameTextBox.Text and i used this variable in invoke command eg. New-AdUser -GivenName $using:user and it worked. But i dont want to declare all variables before

Comment: As a general rule, I always bind my control properties and use the bound values as the content source. That has the added benefit of frequently allowing me to change the type of control used to present the data without having to change the code used to harvest that data.

Comment: Thank you for you advice. I will consider it. Its my first time to build a gui. I solved the problem above. I just created an array with all informations and used this in the remote session it worked. Thank you for your help

Comment: You are welcome. And your solution is effectively following that advice... in a brute force sort of way. :)